# PHP Form Displays Web Server instead of Sender

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm fairly new to this but I've done all the digging I can do. When I submit this form rather than displaying the sender's email (which is what I want) it displays the webserver I'm using in the From part. I'm not sure what I need to put to make display anyone's email.

```
<?php
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $recipient = "my@email.com";
  $subject = "Email Notice";
  $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
  if(mail($recipient, $subject, $headers)){
    header("Location: thankyou.html");
  }else{
    header("Location: sorry.html");
  }
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263061/problem-with-php-mail-from-name-doesnt-appear-correctly). The thing with the `From` header though, depending where the code is hosted, it may be stripping out that header when it hits the first email server.

Comment: This is what email spoofing is known as. Your server will be flagged, your mail will go into spam folders on common providers. The subject may contain their email, but the to field cannot. Please [have a thorough read of the Senders Policy Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework). If you are authorized to send mail for this domain, exist in their SPF, or the web server is the same as the mail server for the domain in the email address, you can do this. If not, you *should not* do this.

Comment: It only posts From in the header part of the email, and doesn't display anything afterward. Is it a security thing that I'm missing. As I'm reading through the Senders Policy from what I understand I am authorized to send mail through my mail server. I just thought it might be a PHP goof.